# Where can I find sample Lidar data for counties in Florida

Tags: geospatial, data.gov, noaa

I would like to find out where I could download Lidar data for counties in Florida

Comment: Internet search for “Florida lidar” shows several results. Any reason why not?

Comment: earthexplorer.usgs.gov may also help

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking or point cloud data (las files) for counties in Florida. I was able to find them at Data.gov web site.  
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/lidar-point-cloud-usgs-national-map